# Pyspark regexp_extract does not recognize '=' as a character?

Tags: sql, regex, string, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to write a regular expression to match the urls that have text.csv, followed by a single letter parameter, followed by a set of characters that is between 10-25 characters.

I have this expression, which works with pandas, but does not work in Pyspark..

`text.csv\?[a-z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,25}$`

I have found that the problem is with the `=` sign, but I am not sure how to fix it. Here is a reproducible example.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions, types

data2 = [("http://daasd.com/text.csv?c=uss1zhv1imikb4w", 2),
         ("http://oasnd.com/car.csv?c=913fh7n83n19ms98", 4),
         ("http://dunfdas.com/bread.csv?c=4968698835", 8),
         ("http://dasuugfb.com/meat.csv?c=0uhkmr9dvs3hs", 7),
         ("http://daosj.com/text.csv?c=h7hgk1r3o3", 1),
     ("http://daosj.com/text.csv?c=h7hg", 1),
  ]

schema = types.StructType([ \
    types.StructField("url", types.StringType(),True),\
    types.StructField("val", types.IntegerType(),True),
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=schema)

my_regex = r'text.csv\?[a-z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,25}$'
df = df.withColumn('is_match', functions.expr(f"regexp_extract(url, '{my_regex}', 0) != ''"))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

```
# --- Result ---
+--------------------------------------------+---+--------+
|url                                         |val|is_match|
+--------------------------------------------+---+--------+
|http://daasd.com/text.csv?c=uss1zhv1imikb4w |2  |false   |
|http://oasnd.com/car.csv?c=913fh7n83n19ms98 |4  |false   |
|http://dunfdas.com/bread.csv?c=4968698835   |8  |false   |
|http://dasuugfb.com/meat.csv?c=0uhkmr9dvs3hs|7  |false   |
|http://daosj.com/text.csv?c=h7hgk1r3o3      |1  |false   |
|http://daosj.com/text.csv?c=h7hg            |1  |false   |
+--------------------------------------------+---+--------+

# -- Desired Result --
+--------------------------------------------+---+--------+
|url                                         |val|is_match|
+--------------------------------------------+---+--------+
|http://daasd.com/text.csv?c=uss1zhv1imikb4w |2  |True    |
|http://oasnd.com/car.csv?c=913fh7n83n19ms98 |4  |false   |
|http://dunfdas.com/bread.csv?c=4968698835   |8  |false   |
|http://dasuugfb.com/meat.csv?c=0uhkmr9dvs3hs|7  |false   |
|http://daosj.com/text.csv?c=h7hgk1r3o3      |1  |True    |
|http://daosj.com/text.csv?c=h7hg            |1  |false   |
+--------------------------------------------+---+--------+
```

Any ideas?

Spark version: 3.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `.rlike` function.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions, types
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

data2 = [("http://daasd.com/text.csv?c=uss1zhv1imikb4w", 2),
         ("http://oasnd.com/car.csv?c=913fh7n83n19ms98", 4),
         ("http://dunfdas.com/bread.csv?c=4968698835", 8),
         ("http://dasuugfb.com/meat.csv?c=0uhkmr9dvs3hs", 7),
         ("http://daosj.com/text.csv?c=h7hgk1r3o3", 1),
     ("http://daosj.com/text.csv?c=h7hg", 1),
  ]

schema = types.StructType([ \
    types.StructField("url", types.StringType(),True),\
    types.StructField("val", types.IntegerType(),True),
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=schema)

my_regex = r'text.csv\?[a-z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,25}$'
df = df.withColumn('is_match', col("url").rlike(f"{my_regex}"))

df.show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------------------------+---+--------+
#|url                                         |val|is_match|
#+--------------------------------------------+---+--------+
#|http://daasd.com/text.csv?c=uss1zhv1imikb4w |2  |true    |
#|http://oasnd.com/car.csv?c=913fh7n83n19ms98 |4  |false   |
#|http://dunfdas.com/bread.csv?c=4968698835   |8  |false   |
#|http://dasuugfb.com/meat.csv?c=0uhkmr9dvs3hs|7  |false   |
#|http://daosj.com/text.csv?c=h7hgk1r3o3      |1  |true    |
#|http://daosj.com/text.csv?c=h7hg            |1  |true    |
#+--------------------------------------------+---+--------+
```